# Followed a Rails tutorial and got Action controller: Exception caught?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the [railstutorial.org tutorial about microposts.](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts)

I'm having the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Pages#home

Showing /home/alex/apps/sample_app/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb where line #1 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.errors
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% if @user.errors.any? %>
2:   <div id="error_explanation">
3:     <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> 
4:         prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> user from being saved:</h2>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb, app/views/pages/home.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/alex/apps/sample_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb__227730281_80967500'
app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb___680753694_80558240'
app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb___680753694_80558240'
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__571228236_80133470'
```

**_error_messages.html.erb:**

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> 
        prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> user from being saved:</h2>
    <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**home.html.erb:**

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <table class="front" summary="For signed-in users">
    <tr>
      <td class="main">
        <h1 class="micropost">What's up?</h1>
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
      </td>
      <td class="sidebar round">
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% else %>
  <h1>Sample App</h1>

  <p>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </p>

  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, :class => "signup_button round" %>
<% end %>
```

**_micropost_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**microposts_controller.html.erb:**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

**pages_controller.html.erb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
        @title = "Home"
    @micropost = Micropost.new if signed_in?
  end

  def contact
        @title = "Contact"
  end

    def about
        @title = "About"
    end

  def help
    @title = "Help"
  end
end
```

I've been checking the tutorial over and over again and everything looks exactly the same.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Can you show the corresponding controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have a `@user` variable in your `home` action. Hence, `@user` is nil. Assuming you followed the authentication sections exactly, try the assignment: `@user = current_user`.

Comment: Hey it worked. Strange, how come it wasn't mentioned in the tutorial? That tutorial is widely recognized as the best rails tutorial ever made.

Comment: After some searching, I found that in listing 10.4, the tutorial updates the `shared/_error_messages.html.erb` file a bit (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code:updated_error_messages_partial). Compare to the prior listing 8.9 (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code:errors_partial). Your version of the partial is more like 8.9, but it should have looked like 10.4

Answer (score 0):

`@user` is `nil` at this point:

```
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% if @user.errors.any? %>
```

`nil` does not have the property `errors`, hence an exception is thrown.

Comment: But how come the tutorials shows a perfectly rendered page. What should I do so that I can have the same outcome as in the tutorial?

Comment: You should make sure `@user` is not nil. Make sure that, in you controller, you're creating the `@user` variable to be read in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the home action in the Pages controller. Can you post the code from Pages#home?

Edit:
Yeah, see you haven't defined a user - @user.

Answer (score 0):

For _error_messages.html.erb, all `@users` should be `object`.

Here is my copy of _error_messages.html.erb:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %> 
        prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> 
        from being saved:</h2>
    <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```